# How to use regex URL to query a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

The following queries column A in a published Google Spreadsheet. The result is all rows with text `comment` in them.

```
var word = "comment";    
var id = "unBCxSc8hR41dg6s6N3d17uccj8jnK5Xsn68C58Y76r9";
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+id+"/gviz/tq?tq=SELECT%20*%20where%20A%20contains%20%22"+word+"%22";
```

Please tell me what changes should I make to the URL in order to use regex.

For example, I need to find all rows with pattern `co..en.*` or `.*ment` in them.

~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~·~

**EDIT**

After Tanaike's help:

```
var word = "f.*t";
var columna = "A";
var id = "4tz810VLT4qv7Q9t94p24tz810VLT4qv7Q9t94p24tz8";
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+id+"/gviz/tq?tq=select%20"+columna+"%20where%20A%20matches%20%27"+word+"%27";
```

This will match *fit, faint, font, fruit, feet, fat, etc.*

*~ finis ~*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values using the regex of `co..en.*` or `.*ment`.
- You want to achieve this using the query language of Google Visualization API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just on of several possible answers.

In this case, how about using `matches`? The modified query is as follows.

#### Modified query:

```
select * where A matches 'co..en.*|.*ment'
```

In this case, in order to use this query, please encode it with the URL encode. So when your endpoint is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
tq=SELECT%20*%20where%20A%20contains%20%22"+word+"%22"
```

#### To:

```
tq=select%20%2A%20where%20A%20matches%20%27co..en.%2A%7C.%2Ament%27
```

#### Reference:

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @iulius Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.